# Share buttons on article footer

Tags: plugins, posts, footer, social-sharing

for a website I need to place facebook and twitter share buttons on the footer section of each article on the blog page (where are listed all the articles).

I tested many social plugin and was able to have this result only using ShareThis. (I've tested without luck also Sharebar, Sociable and Social likes).

Unfortunately Sharethis has a layout bug on my website that cuts off few pixels from the buttons, you can see it on this screenshot:

http://postimg.org/image/gdog4h8nz/

I have no clue on how to fix this since I have no control on the nested span tags that build those buttons.

Does anyone know a way to fix that border issue, or knows another social plugin that does the same and works better?

EDIT:

This is the code I see on notepad++:

```
    <div class="entry-content">
    <?php 
    $share = "<span class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook'></span><span class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet'></span>";
    //the_content( __( $articlefooter, 'twentythirteen' ) );
    the_content( __( '<footer id="sv-align-right" class="entry-meta">'.$share.'<span id="sv-read-article" class="btn btn-default">Continua a leggere <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span></span></footer>', 'twentythirteen' ) );
    ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

The code inside the $share variable gets replaced in runtime by ShareThis script, and becomes much bigger with a lot of nested span tags:

```
<footer id="sv-align-right" class="entry-meta">
<span class="st_facebook_hcount" displaytext="Facebook" st_processed="yes">
<span style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;"     class="stButton">
<span>
<span class="stMainServices st-facebook-counter" style="background-image: url(http://w.sharethis.com/images/facebook_counter.png);">&nbsp;
<img src="http://w.sharethis.com/images/check-big.png" style="position: absolute; top: -7px; right: -7px; width: 19px; height: 19px; max-width: 19px; max-height: 19px; display: none;"></span><span class="stArrow">
<span class="stButton_gradient stHBubble" style="display: inline-block;">
<span class="stBubble_hcount">0
</span></span></span></span></span></span>
<span class="st_twitter_hcount" displaytext="Tweet" st_processed="yes">
<span style="text-decoration:none;color:#000000;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;" class="stButton">
<span>
<span class="stMainServices st-twitter-counter" style="background-image: url(http://w.sharethis.com/images/twitter_counter.png);">&nbsp;
<img src="http://w.sharethis.com/images/check-big.png" style="position: absolute; top: -7px; right: -7px; width: 19px; height: 19px; max-width: 19px; max-height: 19px; display: none;">
</span>
<span class="stArrow">
<span class="stButton_gradient stHBubble" style="display: inline-block;">
<span class="stBubble_hcount">0
</span></span></span></span></span></span>
<span id="sv-read-article" class="btn btn-default">Continua a leggere <span class="meta-nav">»</span></span>
</footer>
```

I have found the nested span tag that can be edited to fix the issue, but I have no control over it. I treied to add height to the class stMainservices, like this:

```
.stMainServices {
    height:24px;
}
```

but from Chrome I see that the style gets overwritten somehow.

Comment: I use Sociable and it is pretty neat, but it looks like you've already tried it and it doesn't work you. If I understand correctly from the photo, it looks like a CSS problem. Why don't u give us a link to the website so it's easier to help u?

Comment: Unfortunately the website is on localhost, so I have no way to show you the website. I will edit the question to add some code, hope it will help.

Comment: @kat_indo does Sociable allow to place the buttons anywhere you want? I used ShareThis because of this feature and I didn't find it on Sociable, but maybe I have overlooked it. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses genericons. The original code was derived from [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98392/list-repeating-share-links) I asked, and answered by toscho, so credit goes to him for the original code that lead to the code in this answer. Check it out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98407/31545)

First, download and intall the [genericon pack](http://genericons.com/) in your theme. Enqueue the genericon stylesheet

```
function enqueue_genericon_style() {
      wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.0.2' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_genericon_style' );
```

Add the following to your functions.php. This functions do all the hard work by adding the share url and genericons

```
function pietergoosen_social_share_buttons() {
    $services = array (
        'facebook' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=%1$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Share on Facebook.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-facebook"></span>'
        ),
        'twitter' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://twitter.com/home/?status=%1$s%%20-%%20%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Tweet this post!', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-twitter"></span>'
        ),
        'googleplus' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://plus.google.com/share?url=%1$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Google+1.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-googleplus"></span>'
        ),
        'linkedin' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s&amp;summary=%3$s&amp;source=%4$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('linkedin.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-linkedin"></span>'
        ),
        'reddit' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://reddit.com/submit?url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Reddit.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-reddit"></span>'
        ),
        'stumbleupon' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('StumbleUpon.', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-stumbleupon"></span>'
        ),
        'digg' => array (
            'url'  => 'http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&amp;url=%1$s&amp;title=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Digg this post!', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-digg"></span>'
        ),
        'gmail' => array (
            'url'  => 'https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&amp;fs=1&amp;to&amp;su=%1$s&amp;t=%2$s',
            'text' => esc_attr(__('Share with Gmail', 'pietergoosen' )),
            'icon' => '<span class="genericon genericon-mail"></span>'
        )
    );

    $title    = the_title_attribute( array ( 'echo' => FALSE ) );
    $url      = urlencode( get_permalink() );
    $summary  = the_excerpt();
    $source   = '';

    print '<h4>' . __( 'Share this post with others', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</h4>';

    echo '<div class="socialgenericons service">';

        foreach ( $services as $name  => $service )
        {
            $href = sprintf( $service['url'], $url, urlencode( $title ), urlencode( $summary ), urlencode( $source ) );
            $genericon = $service['icon'];

            printf(
                '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" alt="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
                $href,
                $service['text'],
                $genericon
            );
        }

    echo '</div>';  
}
```

Now add `<?php pietergoosen_social_share_buttons(); ?>` in your content.php where you need to display the buttons.

To open a pop-up when a link is clicked, add the following in your `enqueue_genericon_style()` function.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'pietergoosen-socialshare', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/socialshare.popup.js', array( 'jquery' ), '' , true );
```

Now create a js folder in your theme if you don't have one. Create a file called `socialshare.popup.js` in the js folder. Now add the following in that file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery('.socialgenericons.service a').live('click', function(){

        newwindow=window.open($(this).attr('href'),'','height=450,width=700');

        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}

        return false;

    });

});
```

This should do the trick. Your buttons will look like this. You just need to style the genericons accordingly

[image: Social buttons]

**EDIT**

I use a custom excerpt, so I changed that to `the_excerpt()` for the purpose of this answer, otherwise you will get a fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you should be able to include the following code in your theme file somewhere. You would need to upload the appropriate icons.

```
//Facebook Share
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=<?php echo get_permalink() . '&p[title]=' . get_the_title(); ?>"><img src="[facebook icon url]" /></a>

//Twitter Share
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo get_permalink() . '&text=' . get_the_title(); ?>"><img src="[twitter icon url]" /></a>

//Google+ Share
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><img src="[google+ icon url]" /></a>
```

I'm sure there are others that use a standard URL for sharing, but you get the point. Sorry in advance for any typos.

Comment: I'll give a try to your solution

Comment: It seems to work. Much simpler than the accepted answer. A downside with a production or shielded environment though: I can't confirm this works until the site I'm working on goes live. Working on localhost and on a live server with IP based restrictions during development. So the social media sites cannot find the articles to share.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution. I had the same problem with my Elegant Themes "Divi", but not other themes. I asked and in support forum the answer is in CSS:

```
.stButton .stFb, .stButton .stTwbutton, .stButton .stMainServices {
    height: 28px !important;
}
```

Also, for the count bubble:

```
.stHBubble {
    height: 22px !important;
}
```