# How to share post?

Tags: posts, social-sharing

I found this code that will share my post in social medias but right now it share the whole page and not the individual post. How do I make it share only the individual post? I know its something with the url i the code but dont know what to change it to.

This is the loop for the post.

```
<!--<the loop>-->
            <?php $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 
                                                "cat" => "1", 
                                                "posts_per_page" => "15", 
                                                "post_type" => "post",
                                                "paged" => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
                                                )                                               
                                        );
            while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <!--<cat title>-->
                <div class="tm_catpost_titles">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                            <h1 class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <?php $tit = the_title('','',FALSE); echo substr($tit, 0, 150); if (strlen($tit) > 150) echo " ..."; ?>
                            </h1>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <!--</cat title>-->     
<!--<cat item>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_item">
                    <div class="tmpost-<?php the_ID(); ?>-item">
                        <div id="catpostup">    
                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_1">
                        <?php _e('Av', 'tm_myid_text'); ?> <?php the_author(); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_2">
                        I <?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tm_catpost_item_3">
                        <?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?>
                        </div>


                    </div>
</div>
                </div>
                <!--</cat item>-->

                <!--<cat image>-->
                <div class="tm_cat_image">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'Full' ); ?>
                    </a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!--</cat image>-->

                <div class="tm_cat_desc_home5">
                    <div class="tmpost-desc">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tm_cat_readmore">

                        <div class="tmpost-readmore">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank">
                                 <?php comments_number(__('(0) Kommentarer ', 'tm_myid_text'), __('(1) Kommentar', 'tm_myid_text'), __( '(%) Kommentarer', 'tm_myid_text') );?> 
                            </a> 


                        </div>

                    </div>
                <!-- I got these buttons from simplesharebuttons.com -->
<div id="share-buttons">

<!-- Facebook -->
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="http://alskadehem.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>

<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>

<!-- Google+ -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/google.png" alt="Google" /></a>

<!-- Tumblr+ -->
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.alskadehem.se" target="_blank"><img src="http://alskadehem.se/wp-content/plugins/simple-share-buttons-adder/buttons/somacro/tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr" /></a>

<!-- Pinterest -->
<a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/pinterest.png" alt="Pinterest" /></a>

<!-- Email -->
<a href="mailto:?Subject=Simple Share Buttons&Body=I%20saw%20this%20and%20thought%20of%20you!%20 <?php the_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php the_title(); ?>"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/email.png" alt="Email" /></a>

</div>
                </div>
            </div>
<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>
<div id="ad"></div>
<?php endif; $count++; ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!--</the loop>-->
```

Comment: Please trim your code to highlight *just* the post-sharing.

Comment: Did you mean like that?

Comment: Much better, thanks. Now: assuming you want to replace "`url=http://www.alskadehem.se`" with a post-specific URL, *what have you tried*?

Comment: There is a more elegant way to do this. Have a look at my [answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139377/31545).

Comment: thank for that, but that it so advanced for me to understand

Comment: @PieterGoosen i tried this code from that post but i just get error :
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=<?php echo get_permalink() . '&p[title]=' . get_the_title(); ?>"><img src="http://alskadehem.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>

Comment: I would suggest that you need to have a look at a social sharing plugin. This would really make your job easier. There are a couple out there, you will just need to download a few and test which one works best

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the URL paths with:

```
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
```

Also consider replacing the title or description text for each button with:

```
<?php the_title(); ?>
```

Here's an example:

```
<!-- Twitter -->
<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink(); ?>&text=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" /></a>
```

This code has been tested within single.php with a standard loop.

Comment: HOw do I change the one for pinterest and mail to? I want them to be able to mail the post not open a blank email?

Comment: I tried your code for facebook and twitter but i just get an error and it dosent work.

Comment: "*HOw do I change the one for pinterest and mail to*" - that question is not **specific to WordPress**.

Comment: What error message are you getting? + What @ChipBennett said.

Comment: the error message i get is the page cannot be found. oh sorry i thought it was wordpress related if i wanted to be able to email the post. my bad

Comment: I have fully tested the code within single.php and it works perfectly. Is your code within the loop?

Comment: I dont have a singel.php the page has a own index and the code is inside the loop. I have past the loop  in my question

Comment: The snippet I've provided in my answer is designed to work within single.php. Sorry I couldn't be of further assistance.