# Call a function for social sharing

Tags: plugins, templates

Using this [tutorial](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-social-media-share-buttons-without-plugin) I was able to create sharing buttons, but the problem that the code inject right after `the_content();`, I would like to have the ability to call anywhere in my templates. My understanding that `add_filter('the_content')` is the reason for that, so how can I change it to call it anywhere.

```
function social_buttons($content) {
    global $post;
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $title = get_the_title();
    if(!is_single() && !is_page()) {
        $content = $content . '<div class="contentBottom">
        <ul class="share">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>شارك</a>
                <ul class="social">
                   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$permalink.'"
             onclick="window.open(this.href, \'facebook-share\',\'width=580,height=296\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text='.$title.'&url='.$permalink.'"
            onclick="window.open(this.href, \'twitter-share\', \'width=550,height=235\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$permalink.'"
           onclick="window.open(this.href, \'google-plus-share\', \'width=490,height=530\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="printComment">
            <li><a href="javascript:window.print()" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>طباعة</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>شارك بالتعليق</a></li>
        </ul></div>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'social_buttons');
```

Comment: See [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139377/31545)

Comment: I was looking at it actually, but it will make me change the whole build. Is it possible to fix my code?

Comment: @ShadyMRasmy it return with this error: Warning: Missing argument 1 for social_buttons(), defined line 1

Comment: if you remove `return $content` there will be no output. call it like `echo social_buttons('')` with an empty string as argument to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Milo do you mean to put echo social_buttons('') after return $content; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually link to the wrong post although [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139377/31545) should still help you. The actual post I wanted to link to was [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/98407/31545)

You should use this second link as a guide as there are some issues with your code, although not major. The biggest concern here is your repetition of code

To get back to what you actually need, you have to remove the filter and all instances of `$content` which is passed by reference to the `the_content` filter.

You can simply modify your existing code to the following

```
function social_buttons() {
    global $post;
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    $title = get_the_title();
    if(!is_single() && !is_page()) { ?>
        <div class="contentBottom">
        <ul class="share">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i>شارك</a>
                <ul class="social">
                   <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$permalink.'"
             onclick="window.open(this.href, \'facebook-share\',\'width=580,height=296\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share?text='.$title.'&url='.$permalink.'"
            onclick="window.open(this.href, \'twitter-share\', \'width=550,height=235\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url='.$permalink.'"
           onclick="window.open(this.href, \'google-plus-share\', \'width=490,height=530\');return false;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                   <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="printComment">
            <li><a href="javascript:window.print()" rel="nofollow"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>طباعة</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i>شارك بالتعليق</a></li>
        </ul></div>
    <?php 
}
}
```

You can now call the function where you like as follows

```
social_buttons();
```

Comment: no more errors, thanks to you. just a curly bracket missed at the end of the code

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Thanks for the feedback. Must admit, did not test the code, you are correct, missing a curly at the end. Enjoy :-)